# WPF BitmapImage can`t be serialized/added into a Resource file

Tags: wpf, image, file, resources, addition

why can I not add a wpfImage of type BitmapImage/BitmapSource/ImageSource to a Resource file.

Yes its not serializeable... So how can I workaround this? I need to put my bitmapImages in a Resource file with key/value access programatically.

```
   using (ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter("TBM.Resource"))
   {
         writer.AddResource(fileExtension, wpfImage);
         writer.Generate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resx files were not designed to be used with WPF images. They work fine with GDI images though, so you can save the image to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, and add it to the resource file.

```
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Write the WPF image to the stream
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wpfImage));
    encoder.Save(stream);

    // Rewind the stream
    stream.Position = 0;

    // Read the stream to a GDI image
    var bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

    // Add the GDI image to the resource file
    writer.AddResource(fileExtension, bitmap);
}
```

Comment: I knew that converting to `System.Drawing.Bitmap` would be the solution to this, just didn't know how to reliably do the actual conversion (since you could try to get a stream from `BitmapImage.StreamSource` which of course is not always used). Looks nice, did you test it?

Comment: @H.B., I didn't test this specific code, but I used this technique before

Comment: I wanted to avoid saving the image of type Icon/Bitmap in the Resource, but it seems there is no other way. WPF and Resource files are 2 worlds. Thx for the code, I have a similar one also from SO ;-)

Comment: this is what I use: public static BitmapImage ConvertGDIImageToWPFBitmapImage(this System.Drawing.Bitmap gdiImage)
        {   
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            gdiImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();

            bImg.BeginInit();
            bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
            bImg.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
            bImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.Default;
            bImg.EndInit();

            ms.Close();

            return bImg;
        }